# Maintaining Session while working with a web server

Tags: php, android, session

I am using the simplest way to maintain sessions, which is:

**Just create 1 HttpClient and use it for every server call, which will automatically handle cookies etc..,**

But the problem here is, when i close the application, the HttpClient object is being destroyed, as expected and hence i cannot login.

So i fixed it, this way:

**Store user-email and password in shared preferences, every time the application is launched make a call to the login function(this creates a new session) and use the same HttpClient.**

The problem here is, every session in the web server has an expiry duration of 3 years. Where as i am creating a session (Since i am calling login every time user launches the app), every time user launches the app. Which causes session duplication or say unnecessary sessions being created on the server side.

Am i doing it the right way? How can i solve this?

Thank You

Comment: Is there a way to close the session on the server? You could do that every time your app is closed, or change the expiry duration on the sever if you have access to it.

Comment: You mean to say, i must logout when the app is closed??

Comment: Unless your app needs to run in the background (GPS tracking, for instance) the easiest way to do this would be to logout when the app is closed and login when it is opened. if you need to, you could do this automatically so it wouldn't affect users.

Comment: Or if you can work on server side too, make the timeout, after which if session was not active it is automatically closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement your own CookieStore. It's pretty easy: Extend BasicCookieStore, instantiate it and pass it in the HttpContext. You can store it against a sqlite database, or even just dump it to an xml file (but sqlite is lighter). I have it working here, but I don't time to sanitize the code right now.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your app needs to run in the background (GPS tracking, for instance) the easiest way to do this would be to logout when the app is closed and login when it is opened. if you need to, you could do this automatically so it wouldn't affect users. You can still use `SharedPreferences` for the user email and password, just automatically log in when the app is started and log out when the app is closed. Another solution is to lower the server side timeout, but that depends on if you can change the server settings or if it needs to be set that way.